# Postgresql : Removing Duplicates after performing UNION ALL

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, distinct

I have a requirement where i need to remove some rows after Joining two tables using UNION ALL.
Here are the Tables

**Accounts1**

| id | username | department | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | IT | 2000 |
| 2 | Frodo | Accounts | 1000 |
| 3 | Natan | Service | 800 |
| 4 | Kenworth | Admin | 900 |

**Accounts2**

| id | username | department | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Sam | IT | 1600 |
| 6 | Frodo | Accounts | 800 |

Expected Result of the UNION should be

| id | username | department | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Sam | IT | 1600 |
| 6 | Frodo | Accounts | 800 |
| 3 | Natan | Service | 800 |
| 4 | Kenworth | Admin | 900 |

As seen the expected result should contain the records of the least salary from the accounts2 table replacing the records from the accounts1. I have tried with Distinct but that doesnot resolve the requirement. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the logic that records from accounts2 should replace accounts1 always, or only if the salary is less? Is the ID field useful in the result now that you've lost which table the row came from?

Comment: It should replace only if the salary is less.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all` with filtering:

```
select a2.*
from accounts2 a2
union all
select a1.*
from accounts1 a1
where not exists (select 1
                  from accounts2 a2
                  where a2.username = a1.username and a2.department = a1.department
                 );
```

EDIT:

If you want one row per username or username/department from *either* table with the minimum salary, then I would suggest `union all` with `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (username, department) a.*
from ((select a1.*
       from accounts a1
      ) union all
      (select a2.*
       from accounts a2
      )
     ) a
order by username, department, salary;
```

Remove `department` accordingly if you want one row per employee.

Comment: What if we want to replace only if the salary from the account2 table is less than the account1 table

Answer (score 0):

After UNIONing the two sets, I would calculate a Row_number() ON (Group By department, username Order By salary, id).  Then I would wrap that one in one more Select to filter and retain only row_number = 1.

A little more code, but very explicit as to what is being performed and it has the advantage that if either data set happens to contain multiple values for a user you still get the one with the lowest salary.

This is a problem that comes up often where there are multiple records within a group domain and you want to choose "the best" one even if you can't say exactly which one that is.  The row_number() window function allows your Order By to make the best choice float to the top where it will assign the row_number of 1.  You can then filter and retain only the row_numbers=1 as the "best" choice within each domain.  This always means at least two Select statements because window functions are evaluated after Where and Having clauses.